# VSFTPD Passive Mode doesn't work Behind NAT

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

Hey guys so I am trying to allow my friends to connect to my ftp server (I am hosting it on Ubuntu Server 15.04), so I set the pasv_address in the configuration and the port range in the configuration and router.  But it still doesn't work.  Here is what filezilla says:

Response:       227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,203,228).
Command:        LIST
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing

And here is my configuration:
http://pastebin.com/j1ZyK7K8

Comment: Are you sure your ISP allows you to run an FTP server on your internal network? (some ISPs "up-sell" you a "business connection" that *do* allow you to do things like this)

Comment: I used to have it working, a few months ago, but I accidentally crashed the server and I couldn't access it to see what I did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Late answer, but here goes:

I have all the options turned on like you. It is required, but still won't work.

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=xxx
pasv_max_port=yyy
pasv_address=
```

After these 2 lines change, it is working

```
listen_ipv6=NO
listen=YES
```

Answer (score 1):

sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf

pasv_enable=Yes

pasv_max_port=10100

pasv_min_port=10090

---

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 10090:10100 -j ACCEPT

---

sudo ufw allow 10090:10100/tcp

---

Try allowing Anon login to make sure its not a user/pwd problem.
Not sure what pasv_address is. but I have a domain name, so maybe its needed for IP? BTW Check out duckdns for free DNS!

Comment: @derek-lesho: if the above doesn't work, drop me a note @ Fabby below.

Comment: I tried this but I am still having the same error.  When entering passive mode it says:Command: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,39,106).   Why are there 0s instead of the ip?

Comment: Do you want me to send the ip and password of my server so you ssh into it and try to find the problem?